# How can I go from my HTML file which uses jQuery Mobile to my ASPX file with a tag?

Tags: html, asp.net, jquery-mobile, navigation

I have an HTML file with [jquery-mobile](/questions/tagged/jquery-mobile).

I want to have a button to navigate my page to another page which is ASPX.
How can I do it?

I use this code but it's not working:

```
<a href="mngdirect.aspx" data-role="button" data-transition="flow" data-theme="a">Go To Managment Page</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Should use data-ajax="false"

```
<a href="../mngdirect.aspx" data-role="button" data-ajax = "false" data-transition="flow" data-theme="a">Go To managment Page</a>
```

Comment: Alternatively, use `rel=external`.